# Copy call signature to decorator

Tags: python, decorator

If I do the following

```
def mydecorator(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        f(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    wrapper.__name__ = f.__name__
    return wrapper

@mydecorator
def myfunction(a,b,c):
    '''My docstring'''
    pass
```

And then type `help myfunction`, I get:

```
Help on function myfunction in module __main__:

myfunction(*args, **kwargs)
    My docstring
```

So the name and docstring are correctly copied over. Is there a way to also copy over the actual call signature, in this case `(a, b, c)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example using Michele Simionato's [decorator module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) to fix the signature:

```
import decorator

@decorator.decorator
def mydecorator(f,*args, **kwargs):
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

@mydecorator
def myfunction(a,b,c):
    '''My docstring'''
    pass

help(myfunction)
# Help on function myfunction in module __main__:

# myfunction(a, b, c)
#     My docstring
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but creates a dependency on yet another unofficial third party.  Is there a simple way to do this without using the decorator module?

Comment: The `decorator` module is a single file consisting of < 250 lines. I don't think ripping out the relevant parts will save you much code. The easiest way is to install the decorator module. Note that if you can not install it system-wide, you can always save a local copy of `decorator.py` to a directory in your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: This solution doesn't fit my problem because `decorator` assumes little or no work is done on the parent decorator function, and most of work is done in the inner returned function. That is not my case: I do a lot of work before defining my returned function. Also, it assumes I will actually call the orinal function from inside the returned function, what I won't do (it is an RPC system) so I have no use for function received as the first parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Try the `decorator` module, available here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator/3.2.0

Relevant portion of the docs: http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/decorator/documentation.html#statement-of-the-problem

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is supplied by the Python standard library's [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html), specifically by inspect.getargspec.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def f(a, b, c=0, *args, **kwargs): return
... 
>>> inspect.getargspec(f)
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', defaults=(0,))
```

Comment: This looks interesting, but is there then a way to actually set the call signature of the wrapper so that it looks the same as that of the original function when using the help command?